# How to make ADB wireless working in Android 11?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, jetbrains-ide

I am trying ADB wireless in Android 11 without cable.

1. Wireless ADB debugging enabled
2. Phone and Laptop on the same network
3. ADB updated to the latest version
4. Android studio updated to the latest version
5. Android device shows paired devices list
6. Terminal shows successfully connected

Still cannot see the device in ADB devices or in the RUN section of Android studio (i.e. cannot run the application to connected device)

Look at the screenshots below, what could be the problem here?

[image: Studio screenshot adb]

[image: Phone Screenshot]

[image: Phone Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

you've to connect the device with `adb connect ip:port`

so according to the screenshot it should be `adb connect 192.168.1.101:41743`

Answer (score 0):

You this package to scan QR from command line

https://www.npmjs.com/package/adb-wifi

```
npm i -g adb-wifi
```

and run

```
adb-wifi
```

Scan the QR code

Make sure you are in same wifi